# Difference between ESOP-8 and SOP-8?

Tags: packages, soic

I am ordering some parts for the first PCB projects I've designed in EasyEDA.

One of the PMICs I am utilizing is the [TP4056](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/PMIC-Battery-Management_TP4056_C16581.html) which is listed as being in a "SOP-8_EP_150mil" package.
Doing a broader search on LCSC I came across [this](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/PMIC-Battery-Management_TPOWER-TP4056_C382139.html) IC which listed its package as being "ESOP-8" and is slightly cheaper.

I read through the Wikipedia listing for [SOIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Outline_Integrated_Circuit) and their [list of packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrated_circuit_packaging_types#Small_outline_packages) but I did not find any references to "ESOP".

So my main question is, what are the differences in ESOP (if any), and can I use this as a direct replacement for a standard SOP-8 chip?

Much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: If in even the slightest doubt, examine the package information in the data sheet and compare it to the proposed footprint.  Printing out a 1:1 image of the board and literally setting the parts on it isn't a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package naming is not very standardized. Different vendors can use different names for the same package or the same name for different packages.

It looks like both the parts you have linked are in a variant of SOP-8 with a large pad on the bottom for better thermal dissipation, which is being variously reffered to as "ESOP-8" (tpower LCSC page), "SOP8-PP" (tpower datasheet), "SOP-8_EP_150mil" (nanjing LCSC page) and "8 引脚 SOP-PP" (nanjing datasheet)

(note: I can't actually read any of the text in the data sheets, but it was fairly easy to find the package diagram)